# How to set up a mysql2 connection before an http server starts accepting requests?

Tags: mysql, node.js

```
const http = require('http');
var mysql2 = require('mysql2/promise');
var mysql2Conn;

const httpServer = http.createServer(function(req,res){
    // error handler
    // handlers
    // req.on('data' ...
    // req.on('end' ...

}).listen(config_private.localPort, async function (err){
    // error handler
};
```

Where in there above code should I put

```
mysql2Conn= await mysql2.createConnection({..params..});
```

to get have the server to `.listen` and have `http.createServer`'s eventHandler accept http request AFTER the sqlConn1 is ready?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could `listen` after connecting to `db`, like:

```
const http = require('http');
var mysql2 = require('mysql2/promise');
var mysql2Conn;

const httpServer = http.createServer(function(req,res){
  // error handler
  // handlers
  // req.on('data' ...
  // req.on('end' ...
});

async function init() {
  try {
    mysql2Conn= await mysql2.createConnection({..params..});
    httpServer.listen(config_private.localPort, async function (err){
      // error handler
    });
  } catch(e) {
    console.log('db connection failed');
  }
}

init();
```